# How we can slice elements fetched using cy.get() and then run tests on those specific elements only?

Tags: cypress

```js
cy.get('li').slice(0,5)
```

The above line of code doesn't work as it show the error message:

> Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'Chainable<JQuery>'

Is there a way to slice elements that we have fetched using `cy.get()`?

Comment: Are you trying to slice the inner text of the element ?

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of other ways to do it,

- add pseudo-selector `:lt(5)` to take first 5 items

```js
cy.get('li:lt(5)')
```

- apply a filter to the set

```js
cy.get('li')
  .filter((index,el) => index < 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a small tweak to @agoff's answer, you can use the [`.invoke()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke) command to use `slice` method on your jQuery array, where the first argument will be the method name and the following will be the method arguments.

```js
cy.get('li')
  .invoke('slice', '0', '5')
  .should('have.length', 5)
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/sliceElements.md).

Answer (score 0):

Cypress's `cy.get()` yields a Chainable, which allows Cypress to easily pass elements (and other things) between Cypress commands. To use traditional JS functions, you'll just need to use `.then()`.

```js
cy.get('li').then(($els) => {
  const $sliced = $els.slice(0, 5);
  // whatever you need to do with $sliced.
  // to easily iterate over these, do something like the following
  cy.wrap($sliced) // add the $sliced variable into the Cypress chain
    .each(($el) => {
      // whatever needs to be tested on each element
    });
});
```