# Cypress - Click on several elements with same selector without using {multiple:true}

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, lodash

I have 10 elements with the same selector and I want to click on 5 of them.

The `{multiple:true}` option clicks on all elements.

Tried to use lodash with `Cypress._.times()` but it also returns Cypress Error

> `cy.click()` can only be called on a single element

Comment: The 1st in the [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73209173/5157454) has an option to slice the first 5, and another to filter the array of items by some criteria using filter.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select multiple elements but not all elements, you can yield each element and use some logic to determine if you should click it.

```js
// Assuming .foo yields 10 elements 
cy.get('.foo').each(($el, index) => {
  // Select the first five
  if (index < 5) {
    cy.wrap($el).click();
  }

  // Or select every other element
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    cy.wrap($el).click();
  }
});
```